# How modify the linq query inside a dbCommand interceptor in EF Core 6

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework-core

I need to insert a `userId` filter in all queries that inherit from the `FullEntity` class.

I'm trying to write a `dbCommand` interceptor overwriting `ReaderExecutingAsync` and modifying the `commandText`.

But this is impractical, since I would have make many conditional to validate if I use `WHERE` or not, and use an `AND` tag, etc.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you can get this `UserId` filter from a service you could inject that service into your Db Context and store it in a field, e.g.,

```cs
public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions options, IMyService myService) : base(options) 
    => _userId = myService.UserId;
```

Then `OnModelCreating` you could setup all your entities to have this filter with somethig like:

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
     base.OnModelCreating(builder);
     builder.Entity<FullEntity>().HasQueryFilter(fe => fe.UserId == _userId);
     // All other entities you need to have this filter by default
}
```